# No imprime los números de manera inversa un array en Java

Tags: java, array

Quiero imprimir los números de un array en Java, pero de manera inversa. Cuando lo ejecuto, ingreso los números, pero luego no los muestra.

Les dejo el código:

```
int[] arrayInt = new int[5];
for(int a=0; a<=4; a++){
    arrayInt [a]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese sus números"));
}
for(int b=4; b<=0; b++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arrayInt [b]);
}
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: En el segundo for `for(int b=4; b<=0; b++){` la variable **`b`** debería ser `b--` en lugar de `b++` porque comienzas en 4 y tendrás un problema de índices inexistentes, ya que tu array solo es de tamaño 5. ;)

Comment: Sumando a eso también b>0 b-- ya que nunca seria menor a 4

Comment: @Israel-ICM Igual sigue sin correrlo. Es decir, uno lo ejecuta, te pide los números y ya está. No los muestra

Comment: @Inkinvissible corrige lo que dice @JFrame también, `b >= 0`. ;)

Comment: Muchas Gracias @JFrame. Me sirvió mucho. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas Gracias a los dos! Saludos!

Comment: No olviden poner la solución de esto como respuesta, por favor.

Comment: Ok @Alfabravo, lo agrego.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error que tienes es por que haces mal uso en el segundo *for* donde muestras los valores, en este caso:

```
for (int b = 4; b <= 0; b++) {
```

Debes corregirlo a:

```
for (int b = 4; b >= 0; b--) {
```

Como la variable *b* esta iniciada en 4, si pones `b++` el siguiente será 5 cosa que te dará error porque tu array solo tiene un tamaño de 5, entonces por eso debe ser `b--` y la condición al revés de lo que tenias siendo `b >= 0` para que no tome los valores negativos.

Answer (score 1):

Debes corregir la iteración para imprimir inversamente el array , para 5 elementos inicias en 4 y finaliza si el valor es igual a `0` o mayor (`>= 0`), para esto debes también decrementar (`--`) el valor de `b`:

```
    //for(int b = 4; b <= 0; b++){
    for (int b = 4; b >= 0; b--) {          
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arrayInt[b]);
    }
```

También puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
//Invierte array
for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length / 2; i++) {
     int temp = arrayInt[i];
     arrayInt[i] = arrayInt[arrayInt.length - 1 - i];
     arrayInt[arrayInt.length - 1 - i] = temp;
 }

 //Imprime valores
 for(int i = 0; i<arrayInt.length; i++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arrayInt[i]);        
 }
```

o usando `Collections`

```
    //Convierte array a List
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(arrayInt.length);
    for (int i : arrayInt){
        list.add(i);
    }
    //Invierte orden de List.
    Collections.reverse(list);
    
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list.get(i));          
    }
```